# What does the triple less-than sign (`<<<`) do in PureScript?

Tags: purescript

I've seen this code in [a PureScript program](https://github.com/bodil/purescript-is-magic/blob/master/src/Main.purs#L111), what does `<<<` do?

```
pinkieLogic :: (Tuple Boolean GameObject) -> GameObject -> GameObject
pinkieLogic (Tuple jumpPressed hater) p =
  hated hater p
  (solidGround
   <<< gravity
   <<< velocity
   <<< jump jumpPressed
   <<< clearSound)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`<<<` is the [right-to-left composition operator](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/wiki/Differences-from-Haskell#composition-operator). It's equivalent to `.` in Haskell. It works like this:

```
(f <<< g) x = f (g x)
```

That is, if you have two functions<sup>1</sup> and you put `<<<` between then, you'll get a new function that calls the first function with the result of calling the second function.

So, that code could be rewritten as follows:

```
pinkieLogic :: (Tuple Boolean GameObject) -> GameObject -> GameObject
pinkieLogic (Tuple jumpPressed hater) p =
  hated hater p
  (\x -> solidGround (gravity (velocity (jump jumpPressed (clearSound x)))))
```

[1] Unlike Haskell's `.` operator, `<<<` in PureScript [also works on categories or semigroupoids](https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/language/Differences-from-Haskell.md#composition-operator).